# Error: Can't capture before it is declared ... iOS swift

Tags: swift

My Error appears in the function of "loadMan" saying that can't capture "loadmanTextures" before it is declared. I don't understand what's wrong with it.....I've already added the function of the "loadmanTextures" underneath.  What should I do ???

```
import SpriteKit


class GameScene: SKScene {
var man:SKSpriteNode
var runningManTextures = [SKTexture]()


override init(size: CGSize){

    self.man = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "man_0"))



    super.init(size:size)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    func loadMan() {
        loadManTextures()
        man.position.y -= man.size.height/2
        addChild(man)
    }

    func loadManTextures() {
        var runningAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "man")
        for i in 1...3 {
            var textureName = "man_\(i)"
            var temp = runningAtlas.textureNamed(textureName)
            runningManTextures.append(temp)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is perfectly clear. Perhaps you don't understand the structure of your own code? You have, intentionally or not, put two functions *inside* another function (also called *function-in-function* or *local function*):

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    func loadMan() {
        loadManTextures()
    }
    func loadManTextures() {
    }
}
```

I don't know why you did that. But if you do it, then the first function cannot call the second function, because this is now executable code - the `loadManTextures` declaration must now be *executed* so that this function *exists*, first, before it can be called:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    func loadManTextures() {
    }
    func loadMan() {
        loadManTextures()
    }
}
```

Of course it would make even more sense not to use function-in-function, but to make them all methods:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
}
func loadMan() {
    loadManTextures()
}
func loadManTextures() {
}
```

Now the order does not matter.